# Cannot DRY short hand if-else (conditional ternary Operator) in javascript

Tags: javascript, click, ternary-operator

i have a simple page of html has a button toggles a div,, however all is working fine but i have an if-else statement in my code like this:

```
 if (info.style.display === '' || info.style.display == 'none'){
    info.style.display =  'inline-block';
} else {
     info.style.display =  'none';
}
```

I`m have decided to use short hand statement like so;

```
 info.style.display === ''||info.style.display ==='none' ? info.style.display = 'inline-block' :info.style.display = 'none';
```

but still feeling thats too long and probably can be dried,

well, i have two approaches but each is not the right way:

```
// this solution works but requires two clicks first time run:

 info.style.display ==( ''||'none' ) ?info.style.display = 'inline-block' :info.style.display = 'none';
```

and :

```
 // this solution doesn't work:
  info.style.display == (''||'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none');
```

Her is [>>> My Plunker <<<](https://plnkr.co/edit/ESgGorVc6gsgH7LN8gGQ?p=preview) 
Any idea on this please?
Thank you..

Comment: `''||info.style.display ==='none'` will always check second part as empty string is falsy in JavaScirpt. `info.style.display = info.style.display === '' || info.style.display == 'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none';`

Comment: You should try storing `info.style` or even `info.style.display` in a temporary variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're always assigning, just put the conditional on the right; you can also (if you really want to) use `!info.style.display` instead of `info.style.display == ''`:

```
info.style.display = !info.style.display || info.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
```

Or even taking advantage of the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) though I'm not sure I'd do it:

```
info.style.display = (info.style.display || 'none') === 'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
```

That works because `'' || 'none'` results in `'none'`, but `'anything_else' || 'none'` results in `'anything_else'`.

Comment: Thank you, any idea why is my first solution requires two clicks?

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is the correct way of using this short if-else statement

```
info.style.display = (info.style.display === '' || info.style.display === 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I used the code from  your plunker

Comment: Well, not *my* plunker... :-)

Comment: ...wat i waz lookin' for :)~ ++